# I got an error when I get JSON from website

Tags: json, swift, http, cookies, header

I got an error when I get JSON from website. I guess the website stops me getting data. How can I resolve it?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://stock.xueqiu.com/v5/stock/chart/kline.json?symbol=SH600004&begin=1531842004299&period=day&type=before&count=-142&indicator=kline,ma,macd,kdj,boll,rsi,wr,bias,cci,psy")
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.request(url).responseJSON { (dataResponse) in
            do {
                if dataResponse.data != nil {
                    let json =  try JSON(data: dataResponse.data!)
                    print(json.description)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: trying to convert data to JSON2")
                print(error)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error below this:

```
{
  "error_code" : "400016",
  "error_uri" : "\/v5\/stock\/chart\/kline.json",
  "error_description" : "Encountered an error, please refresh the page or re-login and try again"
}
```

Comment: I don't think your error is related to your code, I suspect the parameters you are sending to the website are incorrect or invalid

Answer (score 0):

When I copied the URL into me browser I got lots of data - not the error as you said.  Dose the code work now?  Perhaps it was a server error...

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the authentication part on your request since the HTTP error received is 403 which is Forbidden